# Azure Web Application Gateway redirecting to Azure Web Application Services after Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-authentication, azure-app-registration

I have an Azure Application Gateway and and Azure Web Application, this web app uses the default domain (xxx.azurewebsites.net). The Application Gateway works fine with the Web App without Azure authentication (e.g. enter the public IP and web app loads on this public IP). But once I enable Azure Authentication, after the user authenticates they are redirected back to the Web App URL (xxx.azurewebsites.net) and not the Application Gateway Public IP address.

Is there a way I can make it redirect back to the Application Gateway Public IP address after authentication without needing to acquire a custom domain.

Comment: Configure the domain used for accessing the application on Web App as well (custom domain). Currently this domain is only configured on App Gateway. The custom domain on the Web App won't really be used because the domain would resolve to App Gateway but the Web App would issue the correct redirects.

Comment: How exactly would I do this?

Comment: If you have your own domain, you have 2 options:

- Add "A" record + add TXT record for authentication
- Add "CNAME" record + add TXT record for authentication

Go to web app service > Under the settings click on custom domains > "+ add custom domain" > follow the instructions.

You can follow this guide too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=root%2Cazurecli

Answer (score 0):

I created application gateway and web app with default domain and app gateway backend status are healthy and works like below:

[image]

In app service I enabled Azure Authentication and it redirected to the Web App URL:

[image]

Now to redirect back to the Application Gateway Public IP address in your app service go to configuration under setting then general setting like below:

[image]

Change the Https only -> `Off` once you turn off, _Restart the app service and make sure to clear cache.

[image]

Now After authentication Application gateway is redirected successfully like below:

[image]